# Can I add a UI action confirmation?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form that displays a record (about 40 fields). I have a button to duplicate the record in instances where a slight change is needed (i.e. A541AB becomes A541AC). I've seen a couple of instances of solutions on the interwebs but I couldn't find one that works for this UI action. Is it possible to create a confirmation box asking if they're sure they want to duplicate the record? Currently, the button is designed using a macro since I'm not very good with Access VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this in VBA by setting a flag to handle the auto-update. Upon clicking the button ask the user and save if the answer is Yes.

```
'Set a flag for manual update
Private mIsUserUpdate As Boolean 'Flag

'Cancel auto-update
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not mIsUserUpdate Then Cancel = True
End Sub

'Save Button - Change 'YourButtonName'
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to duplicate the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
        mIsUserUpdate = True  'flag ON
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    mIsUserUpdate = False 'flag OFF again
End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to use your code without the 'Cancel auto-update portion. Using that disabled my ability to save over records. Thanks again for the help.